# Fear of spreading rabies from clothing to wound

Tags: dogs

I have a dog bitten pants and I suspect he has rabies. The important thing is that the pants have been left in the house for over a month and have not been touched. After about a month I washed it and washed the place of the bite with my palm with soapy water, but there is a wound on the side of my middle finger.
I'm worried now about getting rabies through the wound

Comment: If rabies is common where you live or there's a risk that you'll come into contact with a rabid animal, the only really secure protection is to get vaccinated. There are some stories of people surviving rabies without it, but they all have very severe brain damage and many died a few months later. A complete rabies vaccination takes 3 doses a few weeks apart and only after all 3 doses are you protected. The vaccination also has to be refreshed every 10 years with a single dose.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to a medical SE.

Comment: for clarification. After the bite, I was given three injections, one injection every week. I mean, this The pants incident  happened to me a month after the time of the bite. A week after the last injection. Can vaccination also protect me from this incident?

Comment: And I was also asked about the dog a month after the bite, they told me that it was still alive

Answer (score 3):

If you have a dog bite wound on your hand, and are concerned the dog may have had rabies, you need to seek medical attention immediately. Not ask on the internet, go to a doctor NOW.

If the dog is still alive and is displaying symptoms of rabies, he needs to be seen by a veterinarian immediately. Humane euthanasia is recommended in cases of rabies, as there is no treatment, and the dog could pose significant risk to people and other animals.

As to your other question, the rabies virus does not last long in the environment. The rabies virus is fragile in the environment and will be come inactive/non-infectious after a few hours, once the material dries or become exposed to sunlight. The [CDC guidance](https://www.cdc.gov/rabies/transmission/index.html):

> Different environmental conditions affect the rate at which the virus
> becomes inactive, but in general, if the material containing the virus
> is dry, the virus can be considered noninfectious.

Comment: I think OP meant that they have a piece of clothing that was in contact with a rabid dog and OP is worried to touch that clothing item with a wound on their hand.

Comment: @SerenaT Yes I wasn't sure which

Comment: for clarification. After the bite, I was given three injections, one injection every week. I mean, this The pants incident happened to me a month after the time of the bite. A week after the last injection. Can vaccination also protect me from this incident?

Comment: And I was also asked about the dog a month after the bite, they told me that it was still alive